# Beep works but the bell character makes no sound

Tags: sound, pantheon-terminal, indicator-sound

I need to use a beep sound in a shell script as follow:

```
echo -e '\a'

echo -ne '\007'
```

But it does not work

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the "audible bell" is disabled in Terminal. You can re-enable it by setting `org.pantheon.terminal.settings audible-bell` to `true` using dconf editor or the `gsettings`command

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how to change the sound to one that is more like error? I'm using grunt while development and would like to make it sound like error

Comment: @user60108 That would be a different question. Please submit a new ask